# How to build two different jar packages with maven-assembly-plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

My project consists of three maven packages and application class (in default package). The existing configuration (defined in pom.xml) uses maven-assembly-plugin to create single executable jar-with-dependencies. 
I'd like to add an *execution* *descriptorRef* \ whatever to create a distributalbe jar package that will contain only classes from two packages out of three (one is a mock-up). 
Is it possible?

If I define an  configuration can I make it relate to one  but not the other?

Comment: The mock up sounds like wrongly located in your production code, cause it belongs to the test code 'src/test/java' instead of 'src/main/java'. Can you show your pom file which you already have?

Comment: I had to move it into separate tester project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have absolutely done this. You can configure multiple executions of the Maven Jar Plugin in the `package` phase and specify different includes / excludes for each execution.

See [Maven Jar Plugin documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/usage.html), particularly the section entitled: "How to create an additional attached jar artifact from the project."

If you must use the Assembly plugin, you should just create a new assembly descriptor using the jar-with-dependencies as a template, but adding the inclusions / exclusions to your liking.

Comment: thanks, @noahlz, looks like it should do the trick. Do you have any relevant example of assembly descriptor with template? Thanks.

Comment: In fact, these are documented. So you just need to copy paste the descriptor and add your own includes/excludes: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html#jar-with-dependencies